# Steps to rebase two GIT Branch

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase, mergetool

I have two GIT branch 1) v1 and 2) v2. I have made changes in both the branch. V1 is the latest branch. I want to merge the changes I have made in v2 into v1 and keep v1 branch.

I took following steps

```
git checkout v2
git pull origin v2
```

**This gave me < v2 | merging> prompt**

```
git rebase v1
git mergetool
```

After this I used merge tool to pick and choose my changes. Is this the correct way to copy changes I have made in v2 into v1? How do I get rid of merging prompt and save the changes.

Thank you

Comment: has my answer been helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to merge locally:

1. Checkout and pull changes into *v2* branch:

   ```
   git checkout v2
   git pull origin v2
   ```
2. Checkout and pull changes into *v1* branch:

   ```
   git checkout v1
   git pull origin v1
   ```
3. Merge the branches into *v1* branch:

   ```
   git merge v2
   ```

   I just merge the branched with `git merge`, it will add to some files the merge blocks similar to:

   ```
   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    ...
   ==========
    ...
   <<<<<<<<<<<<
   ```

   Those two part are represents the changes done in `v1`, and `v2` consequently. So uou have to select proper parts, or both parts, or even never parts of code, and removing that block lines `>>>>>>`, `=====`, `<<<<<<` save the file, and add it to *index*.
4. Edit files, add them to index, and commit merge:

   ```
   vim ...
   git add ...
   git commit
   ```
5. Push to *origin/v2*

   ```
   git push origin v1
   ```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Can you please tell me how to edit the files. I mean how will I know what changes are being made in a file in v1 and v2 branch? Does saying git merge v2 at step 3 will open the merge tool?

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite upated the answer